# MultiDb Configuration with Spring r2dbc always uses only one Database

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-r2dbc

I have a simple Multi Database setup to try out Multi Database configuration with r2dbc.
However, it is not working as expected, it always uses the first Database.

```
@Configuration
@EnableR2dbcRepositories(databaseClientRef="postgreDbClient". basePackages={"com.x.y.repo.postgresql"})
public class PostgreSqlConfiguration extends AbstractR2dbcConfiguration{

    @Bean(name="postgresqlConnectionFactory")
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){
      return ConnectionFactories.get("r2dbc:postgresql://<host>:5432/<database>");
    }

    @Bean(name="postgreDbClient")
    DatabaseClient databaseClient(){
      return DatabaseClient.create(this.connectionFactory());
    }


}


@Configuration
@EnableR2dbcRepositories(databaseClientRef="mssqlDbClient". basePackages={"com.x.y.repo.mssql"})
public class PostgreSqlConfiguration extends AbstractR2dbcConfiguration{

    @Bean(name="mssqlConnectionFactory")
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){
      return ConnectionFactories.get("r2dbc:mssql://<host>:1433/<database>");
    }

    @Bean(name="mssqlDbClient")
    DatabaseClient databaseClient(){
      return DatabaseClient.create(this.connectionFactory());
    }


}

com.x.y.repo.postgresql
   -EmployeeRepository.java
   -DepartmentRepository.java

com.x.y.repo.mssql
   -PuchaseRepository.java
   -SalesRepository.java

public interface EmployeeRepository extends R2dbcRepository<Employee, Integer>{

}

public interface PuchaseRepository extends R2dbcRepository<Purchase, Integer>{


}
```

The above is the simple representation of my code.
My requests go to Postgresql always, though basepackage is configured for mssql package `com.x.y.repo.mssql`

Comment: I don't think it is worth as an answer, but that was a terrible mistake. There was a spelling mistake with the ```basePackages``` value. I was assuming a warning or error will be thrown if a non existent package was provided. However, there was no error. Since, this is a Multi-database configuration, it had silently assigned all the repositories to the Default repository. Had to enable debug log and identify this zero repositories found message.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version you are using, I also encountered the same issue when using the latest spring boot 2.4.0-M2/Spring Data R2dbc 1.2.0-M2.

Using `AbstractR2dbcConfiguration` is problematic here, check [this quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63878598/numeric-types-mapping-issue-in-spring-data-r2dbc-with-postgres). I was using MySQL and Postgres in the single application.

I finally resolved it by creating custom config and giving up `AbstractR2dbcConfiguration`, check [the sample codes](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-puzzles/tree/master/multi-r2dbc-connectionfactories).