# Numeric types mapping issue in Spring Data R2dbc with postgres

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

I tried to use Spring Data R2dbc/Postgres in a sample application.

- Spring Boot 2.4.0-M2
- R2dbc Postgres (managed by Spring Boot)
- Spring Data R2dbc 1.2.0-M2(managed by Spring Boot)

The table scripts.

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS ORDERS_ID_SEQ;

CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS ORDERS(
ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('ORDERS_ID_SEQ') ,
CUST_ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
AMOUNT REAL NOT NULL
);

ALTER SEQUENCE ORDERS_ID_SEQ OWNED BY ORDERS.ID;
```

The data.sql:

```sql
-- INSERT SAMPLE DATA
DELETE FROM ORDERS;
INSERT INTO ORDERS(CUST_ID, AMOUNT) VALUES (1, 100.2);
```

I use a `ResourceDatabasePopulator` to populate the data, it works.

But when I was trying to save the data by Repository, failed.

```java
@Table(value = "ORDERS")
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Order implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(value = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(value = "CUST_ID")
    private Long customerId;

    // use BigDecimal or Java Money API in the real-world application.
    @Column(value = "AMOUNT")
    private Double amount;
}


public interface OrderRepository extends R2dbcRepository<Order,Integer> {
}

// in application runner.

orders .save(Order.builder().customerId(c.getId()).amount(201.0).build())
```

It threw an exception like this:

```sh
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Binding parameters is not supported for the statement 'INSERT INTO ORDERS (CUST_ID, AMOUNT) VALUES (?, ?)'
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Binding parameters is not supported for the statement 'INSERT INTO ORDERS (CUST_ID, AMOUNT) VALUES (?, ?)'
    at io.r2dbc.postgresql.SimpleQueryPostgresqlStatement.bind(SimpleQueryPostgresqlStatement.java:78) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-0.8.4.RELEASE.jar:0.8.4.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.postgresql.SimpleQueryPostgresqlStatement.bind(SimpleQueryPostgresqlStatement.java:44) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-0.8.4.RELEASE.jar:0.8.4.RELEASE]
```

The complete codes is [here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-puzzles/tree/master/multi-r2dbc-connectionfactories).

**Updated**: Give up extending from `AbstractR2dbcConfiguration`, and get resovled when following [the official guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/1.1.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#r2dbc.multiple-databases).

Comment: For some reason, parameter bind markers are represented as `?` instead of `$1`, `$2`. Please make sure to use the correct dialect.

Comment: @mp911de Got resolved when giving up the abstract config class.

Comment: Not sure where is the problem, in the `AbstractR2dbcConfiguration`, it also used DiallectResovler to detect dialect from the connectionfactories, I tried to use DiallectResovler in the custom config, it works.